# Goal: querySelectorAll("[data-something=${variableValue}]")

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors

What I want to achieve is dynamically generating dataset value from outside variable, instead of hardcoding it into querySelector?

Comment: ``querySelectorAll(`[data-something="${variableValue}"]`)``?

Comment: @Amadan Backtick strings do not work in every browser and even if they do, this breaks when `variableValue` contains a `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Just build the string - but don't forget to escape it properly.

```
querySelectorAll("[data-something=" + CSS.escape(variableValue) + "]")
```

Where `CSS.escape()` is a helper function that escapes all characters that have special meaning in CSS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape

Comment: By the way. If your website targets audiences that for some reason use IE, there is a polyfill for `CSS.escape` on that MDN site. Just include it for the sake of completeness, there is no reason to shut out IE over such a little thing.